# UIPageView - Controlling Page Turn Speed

Tags: ios5, uipageviewcontroller

Is there any way to control the speed of the page turn animation in my  UIPageViewController? Specifically, slow the animation down when someone swipes really fast. Slow and medium swipes look great but when you swipe fast, the page turn animation looks more like a horizontal slide transition than an actual page turn.

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] 
                      initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                        navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                      options: options];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have ever seen the duration of the page turning controlled is by using cocos2d http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/about

*"cocos2d for iPhone is a framework for building 2D games, demos, and other graphical/interactive applications. It is based on the cocos2d design: it uses the same concepts, but instead of using python it uses objective-c."*

CartoonSmart http://www.cartoonsmart.com/ makes use of it in a Starter Kit for eBooks where they set a transitionWithDuration option, a snippet of which is shown below.

```
-(void) doAfterChangingPages {   
    [[BookData sharedData] turnPage];
    CCTransitionPageTurn* transition = [CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:2 scene:[ThePage scene] backwards:NO];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];
}
```

There is not actually a swipe gesture, although it will seem that there is, simply a touch gesture in a certain area on the outside edge of the page causes the transition. The speed is a constant so that no matter how slow or fast a gesture is performed, the page always turns at the speed as set by the option.